# Solving Symbolic Boolean variables in Python

Tags: python, boolean, sympy, symbolic-math, sage

I need to solve a set of symbolic Boolean expressions like:

```
>>> solve(x | y = False)
(False, False)

>>> solve(x & y = True)
(True, True)

>>> solve (x & y & z = True)
(True, True, True)

>>> solve(x ^ y = False)
((False, False), (True, True))
```

Number of such variables is large (~200) so that Brute Force strategy is not possible. I searched the web and found that [Sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) and [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/index.html) have symbolic manipulation capabilities (particularly [this](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/logic/sage/logic/booleval.html) and [this](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/pbori.html) may be useful). How can I do that?

EDIT: I mainly tried to manipulate such things:

```
>>> from sympy import *

>>> x=Symbol('x', bool=True)

>>> y=Symbol('y', bool=True)

>>> solve(x & y, x)
```

which results in `NotImplementedError`. 
Then I tried  `solve(x * y, x)` which gave `[0]` (I don't know what does it mean), `solve(x * y = True, x)` resulted in a `SyntaxError`, `solve(x * y, True, x)` and `solve(x & y, True, x)` gave an `AttributeError`. I don't know what else to try!

EDIT (2): I also found [this](ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/packages/sagemath/doc/en/reference/sat/sat.pdf), may be useful!

Comment: And what is wrong with the solutions you found? What have you tried? We must not do your evaluation work.

Comment: OK, I found [this](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/logic.html) stating use of Boolean variables, but solution of equations are found [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html), but how to connect this two? `solve` assumes that RHS is `0`, but here how can I put `True` or `False`?

Comment: I think you want to use `satisfiable` not `solve` for boolean expressions as per [this link](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/logic.html).

Comment: @kalhartt [this link](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html) is better. 0.6.7 is a very old version of SymPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to correct a few things that are just blatently wrong in your question:

- `solve` solves for algebraic expressions. `solve(expr, x)` solves the equation expr = 0 for `x`.
- `solve(x | y = False)` and so on are invalid syntax. You cannot use `=` to mean equality in Python. See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs (and I recommend reading the rest of that tutorial as well).
- As I mentioned in the answer to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703284/boolean-operation-with-symbol-in-sympy) question, `Symbol('y', bool=True)` does nothing. `Symbol('x', something=True)` sets the `is_something` assumption on `x`, but `bool` is not a recognized assumption by any part of SymPy. Just use regular `Symbol('x')` for boolean expressions.

As some commenters noted, what you want is `satisfiable`, which implements a SAT solver. `satisfiable(expr)` tells you if `expr` is satisfiable, that is, if there are values for the variables in `expr` that make it true. If it is satisfiable, it returns a mapping of such values (called a "model"). If no such mapping exists, i.e., `expr` is a contradiction, it returns `False`.

Therefore, `satisfiable(expr)` is the same as solving for `expr = True`.  If you want to solve for `expr = False`, you should use `satisfiable(~expr)` (`~` in SymPy means not).

```
In [5]: satisfiable(x & y)
Out[5]: {x: True, y: True}

In [6]: satisfiable(~(x | y))
Out[6]: {x: False, y: False}

In [7]: satisfiable(x & y & z)
Out[7]: {x: True, y: True, z: True}
```

Finally, note that `satisfiable` only returns one solution, because in general this is all you want, whereas finding all the solutions in general is extremely expensive, as there could be as many as `2**n` of them, where `n` is the number of variables in your expression.

If however, you want to find all of them, the usual trick is to append your original expression with `~E`, where `E` is the conjunction of the previous solution. So for example,

```
In [8]: satisfiable(x ^ y)
Out[8]: {x: True, y: False}

In [9]: satisfiable((x ^ y) & ~(x & ~y))
Out[9]: {x: False, y: True}
```

The `& ~(x & ~y)` means that you don't want a solution where `x` is true and `y` is false (think of `&` as adding extra conditions on your solution). Iterating this way, you can generate all solutions.

Comment: And if `satisfiable` ends up being too slow for you, check out other SAT solvers which are written in C. `picosat` for instance may be useful. It will require you to formulate your problem in a more rudimentary way (so-called DIMACS cnf form), but such solvers will return a solution almost instantly even for quite large problems.

Comment: And I should mention that `picosat` has Python bindings, called `pycosat`.

Comment: Great! One thing I would like to add, I found that only one solution is sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: Good thing. Otherwise, it might take a very long time to solve your problem.

Comment: Surprisingly, `satisfiable` doesn't always solve for all of the variables. `satisfiable(Eq(3*A-B,7) & Eq(2*A+3*B,1))` gives `{Eq(2*A + 3*B, 1): True, Eq(3*A - B, 7): True}`, but it doesn't solve for `A` and `B`.

Comment: @AndersonGreen `satisfiable` only does boolean satisfiability. It isn't an SMT solver. If you want to solve equations, use `solve`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got [it](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sat/) (though use of it is still unclear).