# Can I solve this case with Sympy?

Tags: sympy

Simplified example of what I need:

```
a = banana or apple
b = banana or apple

a is not equal to b
a = apple

b = ?
```

So we all know b = banana. But can I give those rules to Sympy and let it calculate for me? I have no idea how and thereby no work in progress to present here- been surfing trough docs for now with no luck.

**Edit**:

Suggestions for other libraries are welcome

Comment: This is more suited for [z3py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm)

Comment: @JohanC can you please post an answer solving this using z3py?

Comment: [Solving Symbolic Boolean variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699210/solving-symbolic-boolean-variables-in-python) seems to indicate that this kind of operations isn't very straightforward in sympy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from z3 import *

p = Int('p')
q = Int('q')

solve(Or(p==1,p==2), Or(q==1,q==2), Not(p==q), p==1)
```

Assuming a,b = p,q and 1 = banana, 2 = apple (or around). Works! Still want to use sympy, but can't calc this.

**Edit**:

For sympy can look into [Solving Symbolic Boolean variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699210/solving-symbolic-boolean-variables-in-python).